# Reading a usb stick

Tags: usb

Hi I recently had a photo shoot of my new born son. They came on a usb but I can't open it in Ubuntu .

Is there anything I can do because other than format it? I don't want to lose the photos. It registers and I can look at disk but is unable to see anything in it.

Comment: Do you know in what format the usb is? Ubuntu can't open some formats by default, but with some extra packages, you can fix it. Also run Gparted to see if the system is recognozing the usb.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an Ubuntu problem. It's worth trying the USB on another machine, preferably one running the same operating system as the photographer.  If you can see the photos there, the simplest solution may be to copy them to a new USB.  Whatever you do, don't format the original USB!

Comment: If you feel that my answer fails to address the question ("Is there anything I can do?"), please feel free to delete it. I do not require clarification from the asker.